# How to make Generics mandatory

Tags: typescript

Is there any way to mark Generics as mandatory in typescript?

```
function onSubmit<Result, Variables>({
    foo,
    bar
  }: {
    foo: Result
    bar: Variables
  }) {
    console.log(foo, bar)
}

// this should not be possible without passing the Generics
onSubmit({ foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar' })

// this works as expected 
onSubmit<number, number>({ foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar' })
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%20%20function%20onSubmit%3CResult%2C%20Variables%3E(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20Result%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20Variables%0D%0A%20%20%7D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(foo%2C%20bar)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AonSubmit(%7B%20foo%3A%20'foo'%2C%20bar%3A%20'bar'%20%7D)%0D%0AonSubmit%3Cnumber%2C%20number%3E(%7B%20foo%3A%20'foo'%2C%20bar%3A%20'bar'%20%7D)%0D%0A%20%20)

## Edit

The question was answered and it works like a charm. To better understand why I want to use this, here's an example.

```
onSubmit<UpdateUserMutation, UpdateUserMutationVariables>({
  mutation: UpdateUserDocument,
  variables: { id: user.id, user: formData },
  refetchQueries: ['GetUserList'],
  onSuccess: ({ data }) => history.push(`/users/${data.updateUser.id}`),
})
```

When I omit `<UpdateUserMutation, UpdateUserMutationVariables>`, I don't know what `data` will be in my `onSuccess` function. Additionally, I don't know which variables I have to pass to the `variables`key. Not to mention the IDE integration :-)

For sure I could type `{ data }` directly, but I think now it's way more comfortable, because I can't "forget" to type and so I will never use wrong/forget to use variables in the `variables` object and the `onSuccess` function.

For the curious one's, this is how my `onSubmit` function looks now:

```
function onSubmit<
  Result = [Error, 'Please specify the Result type parameter'],
  Variables = [Error, 'Please specify the Variables type parameter'],
  R extends Result = Result,
  V extends Variables = Variables
>({
  mutation,
  variables,
  refetchQueries,
  onSuccess,
}: {
  mutation: DocumentNode
  variables: V
  refetchQueries: ((string | PureQueryOptions)[]) | (string | PureQueryOptions)[]
  onSuccess: (response: FetchResult<R, Record<string, any>, Record<string, any>>) => void
}) {
  client
    .mutate<R>({
      mutation,
      variables,
      refetchQueries,
    })
    .then(response => {
      setErrors({})
      onSuccess(response)
    })
    .catch(handleErrors)
}
```

Comment: This is basically asking to turn off type inference. Out of curiousity, why?

Comment: Oh, thats right. Hmmm ... I would like to disable type inference for this particular function, because there are a few more callback functions passed as arguments which should not have further `any`-typed arguments. Hard to explain, but I don't think more than turning off the type inference is possible anyway.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't understand that. :-) Maybe with a more complete example, we'd be able to suggest some other solution. But the current question is interesting anyway.

Comment: I've added an example :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intentionally hobbling type inference seems unfortunate, but if I wanted to, here's how I might go about doing it:

```
function onSubmit<
  Result = [Error, "Please specify the Result type parameter"],
  Variables = [Error, "Please specify the Variables type parameter"],
  R extends Result = Result,
  V extends Variables = Variables
>({
  foo,
  bar
}: {
  foo: R
  bar: V
}) {
  console.log(foo, bar)
}
```

The idea is to use [generic type parameter defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to give us more control over what happens to non-inferred type parameters, and to add some extra type parameters to take away type inference sites from the compiler.  The types `Result` and `Variables` cannot be inferred from the passed in values of the `foo` and `bar` properties; they are not even mentioned anywhere in the type signature.  That means if `Result` and `Variables` are not manually specified, they will default to that weird tuple type of the form `[Error, "error message"]`.  That weird tuple type is a workaround for the lack of an ["invalid" type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23689)  in TypeScript.  I could have chosen `never` instead, but then the error message might be more cryptic.

Anyway `foo` will infer `R`, and `bar` will infer `V`, which must be assignable to `Result` and `Variables` respectively.  What this means is that if you don't specify `Result` and `Variables`, they will default to some error type, and then `foo` and `bar` will be constrained to that error type, and you will get an error:

```
onSubmit({ foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar' }) // error
//         ~~~         ~~~        
// 'string' not assignable to 'Error, "Please specify the Result type parameter"'
// 'string' not assignable to 'Error, "Please specify the Variables type parameter"'
```

If you *do* specify `Result` and `Variables` manually, then `R` and `V` will be constrained to them (and will default to them), so should work the same as your previous version:

```
onSubmit<string>({ foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar' }) // error
//                             ~~~
// 'string' not assignable to 'Error, "Please specify the Variables type parameter"'

onSubmit<number, number>({ foo: 3, bar: 4 }) // okay

onSubmit<number, number>({ foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar' })  // error
//                         ~~~         ~~~
// 'string' not assignable to 'number' x2
```

It's ugly, because the language doesn't want you to do this... type inference is usually a good thing.  But this is what you asked for, so... yay?  Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Wow! This is awesome, exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much :) I'll add my case in the initial question.