# force typescript warning for generic

Tags: typescript

I have this code:

```
class testClass1 {
    public a : number = 1;
};

class testClass2 {
    public b : number = 2;
};

interface InterfaceTest<A,T> {(a : A) : T};

function wrapper<A,B>(func : InterfaceTest<A,B>) {
    return 0;
}

wrapper<testClass1, testClass2>(implementation);
wrapper(implementation);
```

Both calls to wrapper works with no warnings, but I want the second wrapper call to produce warning, because the type was not given to the function call.

How do i achieve this ?

Comment: What do you mean by this (a : A) : T ?

Comment: a function that gets type A and return type T as specifies in the generic interface

Comment: [Does this question have the answer you're after?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55610260/how-to-make-generics-mandatory) But I'd echo the sentiment in the answers there: Why would you want to have to specify the generics directly, when they can be inferred from the `implemention` instance? (assuming that `implementation` implements `InterfaceTest`, which defines both `A` and `T`)